# scrapy - AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'update_settings'?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have found this as solution to my problem.
Get settings and configure to log enabled false.

```python
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler

from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
settings = get_project_settings()
settings.set('LOG_ENABLED', False ,priority='cmdline')

process = Crawler(settings)
process.crawl(BlogSpider)
process.start()
```

However I am getting `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'update_settings'`

Comment: Is the problem solved? Do have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

From `Scrapy 1.0` onwards you should use `CrawlerProcess` instead of `Crawler` to run a Scrapy spider from a script.

See the [latest documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) for more information on that.